# Strict Standards: convertDate()

Tags: joomla3.1

Strict Standards: Non-static method JoomleagueHelper::convertDate() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in

```
<td class="center">
<?php
echo JHtml::calendar(   JoomleagueHelper::convertDate($date),
'match_date'.$row->id,
'match_date'.$row->id,
'%d-%m-%Y',
  'size="9"  tabindex="2" ondblclick="copyValue(\'match_date\')"      onchange="document.getElementById(\'cb'.$i.'\').checked=true"');
 ?>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling convertDate statically, then define it as a static method:

`public static function convertDate() {}`

If you are not the writer of the code, try setting your PHP error reporting level to something other than strict standards.

Comment: public function _getMatches($pid)
{
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = ' SELECT m.id, '
. ' m.projectteam1_id,  '
. ' FROM #__jmatch m '
. ' INNER JOIN #__jpteam AS pt1 ON m.pteam1_id = pt1.id '
. ' INNER JOIN #__jround AS r ON m.round_id = r.id '
. ' WHERE ((m.team1_result IS NOT NULL AND m.team2_result IS NOT NULL) '
. ' OR (m.alt_decision=1)) '
. ' AND m.pteam1_id>0 AND m.pteam2_id>0 ';

$db->setQuery($query);
$res = $db->loadObjectList();
$matches = array();
foreach ((array) $res as $r) 
{
$matches[$r->id] = $r;
}
return $matches;
}

Comment: Thank you all is well, another example on Strict Standards: Non-static method JLGRanking::_getMatches() should not be called statically in